# Read status code from header general in angular 9 post method?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using post method in angular 9 and want to read status code.

service.ts

```
forgotPassword(loginId): Observable<boolean> {
  const data = { loginId: loginId };
  const req = this.httpClient.post<AuthenticationData>('api/reset-password', data);
  return this.handleTokenRequestResponse(req);
}
```

component.ts

```
forgotPassword() {
 const f = this.forgotPasswordForm.value;
 this.authenticationService.forgotPassword(f.loginId)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res.headers);
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask Angular to provide it by specifying which part of the response you are interested in, consider observing "response" (the default option will only observe the body of the response) as demonstrated below:

```
return this.http
  .get(this.baseUrl + "users/activate?mailToken=" + mailToken, { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(
    map((response: HttpResponse<boolean>) => response.status)
  )
```